# Android Studio code suggestions doesn't work for Flutter

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-studio, flutter, dart

I'm experiencing a problem with Android Studio and the Flutter framework.

The code completion suggestions Android Studio shows are now incoherent types when I develop mobile apps with Flutter, but, in Visual Studio Code code completion works fine. (And it used to work in Android Studio too, but i may have broken something without knowing it.)

[Here is Android Studio ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxdGO.png)

[And here is the Visual Studio Code ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTVhn.png)

As you can see, Visual Studio Code proposes all of the types that make sense for this specific attribute. But the Android Studio shows something else entirely -- I cannot even find those types there.

I have tried the following:

- Reinstalled Android Studio.
- Invalidated caches and restarted.
- Re-downloaded the flutter SDK
- Re-downloaded the Dart SDK

I am using the latest versions of Android Studio, Flutter and Dart. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try updating your flutter plugin in Android Studio.

1. Open Android Studio
2. File -> Settings -> Plugin -> Updates

Comment: My Flutter plugin is already up to date. It may have something todo with my environment paths ?

Comment: I don't think so. Although you can also check these two other things:- 1) Check if power save mode is enabled,if so then disable it. Go to File -> Power Save Mode 2) File -> Setings -> Editor -> General -> Code Completion

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, unfortunately still nothing. I'am not in the Save Mode and i played around with Code Completion options with no success.

Answer (score 3):

Settings>Editor>General>Code Completion> Set tick on "Show the documentation popup" and adjust how fast you want it to appear.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try clearing `.packages` `.dart_tool` directory and `pubspec.lock` and then restarting android studio. That worked for me.

I found this solution on github: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/4229#issuecomment-567241643

Comment: I don`t understand "clearing". it means "deleting"?

Answer (score 0):

I am so proud of the stupid things I do , I turned on power saving mode without knowing , what would Powersaving mode does to the IDE

**Find the little guy with a hat icon in the bottom right corner and uncheck power saver mode**

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar issue but I figured out that I have so many tabs open that are split vertically into 4 screens. Suggestions would work on 3 but not the 4th. Not sure what would be causing this but I am fine with only 3!

Answer (score 0):

I found disabling Power Save Mode worked best. The option is under File on the Android Studio menu.
[here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNPGG.jpg)
of how to disable it

Answer (score 0):

Open android studio > preferences > plugin > disable Dart & Flutter > restart > enable Dart & Flutter

[image: Attachment]